alot of <a> tag inject in wordpress website
i found html a tags inject in my wordpress site and i try removed it and file i updata wordpress core files more than one time and not successed here is screen shot
here is the website you can check
https://design-dialogue.com/
enter image description here
i try removed it and file i updata wordpress core files more than one time and not successed

Please read "Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?" as well as [ask] and [edit] your post.

https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/
